# Reverse Effects of jQuery Functions

Tags: jquery

I've been manually setting various buttons to restore content changes caused by another specific button. I don't find it very sustainable, and therefore my question is: Is there a way to reverse changes caused by an event if anything, in this case any other button, is clicked? To make an example:

```
HTML:
<div id="trigger"></div>
<div id=1></div>
<div id=2></div>
<div id=3></div>

CSS:
#trigger {height:10px; width:10px; background-color:red;}
#1 {display:none;}
#2 {display:none;}
#3 {display:none;}

jQuery:
$('#trigger').click(function() {
   $('#1').css('display','block');
   $('#2').css('display','inline-block');
   $('#3').css('display','block');
}),

Desired effect:
$('//anything with a click function that is not #trigger').click(function() {
   // Reverse everything caused by the #trigger, effectively setting the divs to their default states.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a rollBack function and call it.

```
function rollBackTriggerChanges() {
   // rollback to initial state
}
```

**Trigger changes**

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {
   $('#1').css('display','block');
   $('#2').css('display','inline-block');
   $('#3').css('display','block');
});
```

**Rollback everything to previous state**

```
$( "div" ).not( "#trigger" ).click(function() {
  rollBackTriggerChanges();
});
```

In case you just apply style changes only and not adding removing class or any other attribute then a quick way would be something like this

```
<div id="trigger">click</div>
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>

#trigger {height:auto; width:100%;background-color:red;}
#1 {height:auto; width:100%; background-color:white;}
#2 {height:auto; width:100%; background-color:white;}
#3 {height:auto; width:100%; background-color:white;}

$('#trigger').click(function() {
   $('#1').css('background-color','#ff0');
   $('#2').css('background-color','#afd451');
   $('#3').css('background-color','#cd4321');
});
$("div").not("#trigger").click(function() {
  $("div").not("#trigger").removeAttr("style");
});
```

Comment: This is essentially what I've been doing. While it achieves the desired result, the code gets very bloated if applied to several events. I do not wish to be reiterating  the #trigger function with values swapped to their specific, initial states. I'm looking for a lightweight alternative.

Comment: you mean you want something like 1 step rollback ? @yoimpetr ? not rollback to initial state?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off an event by using the off() method:

```
$('body').off('click', '#trigger');
```

http://api.jquery.com/off/

This turns off the click events on the #trigger element. You can also chain methods to reverse whatever happened on a click prior to you turning it off. See the link above for examples.

For your case you could:

```
$('body').off('click', '#trigger')
    // may want to replace '#trigger div' with '#1','#2', and '#3'
    .find('#triger div').css('display','none');
```

Comment: This is interesting. However, the link you've provided consist of largely unfamiliar terminology. Could you make an example of what you described after the link?